# How to use a stack(array) for strings instead of characters or integers in c?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, stack, c-strings, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int top = -1, n;
char stk[25][25];

int stackempty()
{
    if ( top == -1 )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int stackfull()
{
    if ( top == n )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void push( char a[] )
{
    if ( !stackfull() )
    {
        top++;
        strcpy( stk[top], a );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Stackfull" );
    }
}

void pop( char a[] )
{
    if( !stackempty() )
    {
        strcpy( a, stk[top] );
        top--;
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Stackempty" );
    }
}

int main()
{
    char o[50], n = 25;
    push( "Hello World!" );
    push( "Hello World!!!" );
    pop( o );
    printf( "%s", o );
    return 0;
}
```

I have created a 2D array and I am treating it as stack. I pushed two strings in the stack (`Hello World!` and `Hello World!!!`) and popped the string at top but it is printing `stackfullHello World!` instead of printing `Hello World!!!`. Is there any other way of implementing this or any correction in my approach to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an uninitialized variable `n` in the file scope

```
int top=-1,n;
```

Within `main` you declared another local variable `n`

```
char o[50],n=25;
```

So the variable `n` declared in the file scope stays unchanged.

At least you need to initialize the global variable like

```
int top=-1,n = 25;
```

and remove the local declaration of `n`

```
char o[50];
```

Pay attention to that the function `stackFull` is incorrect. The stack is full when `top` is equal to `n - 1` because initially top is equal to `-1`.

So define the function like

```
int stackfull( void )
{
    return top == n - 1;
}
```